# Unable to enable logging using CustomizableTraceInterceptor in Spring 3.0.6

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, logging, tomcat6, spring-3

I have a very simple setup

I have an `applicationContext.xml` file like this :

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" />

    <bean id="customizableTraceInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor">
        <property name="enterMessage" value="Entering $[methodName]($[arguments])" />
        <property name="exitMessage" value="Leaving $[methodName](): $[returnValue]" />
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
        <property name="beanNames">
            <list>
                <value>*Service</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" /> -->
        <property name="interceptorNames">
            <list>
                <value>customizableTraceInterceptor</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="wowService" class="org.daud.WowService" scope="prototype" />
</beans>
```

The controller class is also very simple :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private WowService wowService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

        getWowService().printIt();
        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
        return "hello";

    }

    public WowService getWowService() {
        return wowService;
    }

    public void setWowService(WowService wowService) {
        this.wowService = wowService;
    }

}
```

The web.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>simple-form</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>simple-form</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>simple-form</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

`WowService` is also very simple

```
public class WowService {

    public String printIt() {
        return "daud";

    }
}
```

I have the `spring jars of version 3.0.6`, `aopalliance-1.0.jar` and `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar` in my lib folder and nothing else. But there is no trace being recorded.. i.e there is no logging being done when we enter the method of `WowService`, or when we leave it. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Please post source of org.daud.WowService

Comment: Thx. I have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The following line:

```
new WowService().printIt();
```

does not create object managed by container (Spring) and definition of your bean is not taken into consideration.

The bean definition:

```
<bean id="wowService" class="org.daud.WowService" scope="prototype" />
```

looks fine, but you're not using it.

Change your controller to:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    WowService wowService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

        wowService.printIt();
        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
        return "hello";

    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the code as u said, but still its not working. I have update my code above

Comment: I made some progress (documented at http://www.coderanch.com/t/596705/Spring/Unable-enable-logging-CustomizableTraceInterceptor-Spring) but ultimately had to modify the server's logging.properties, and couldn't find the reason why my application's properties file was not overriding the server's. So, in short, didn't find the correct solution